# How to calculate a probability based on a known probability

Tags: probability

please, if anyone can help me.

I need to know if this statement has a solution and how. I will start to study probability and statistics, but I need to solve this now.

> If the probability of a person of using their fitbit device every day
> for 21 days is 0.802, what is the probability of using it every day
> for 31 days?

Comment: Hint: what is the probability of it happening in any one day? What do you have to assume in order to say that?

Comment: Dave's leading you on the right track. Just off the claim about 21 days, you can't make a claim about 31 days, unless you make certain assumptions about how usage on each day is related.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dave and Arya. My assumption goes as follows: if my sample is 21 days, and the person use the device every single, I think of it like 100% success, and if the result is 0.802, I would say that the probability of using it on any day is 0.802. For that, I could assume that no matters if now I have a sample of 31 days, the result will be always 0.802. But I need to see this resolution in a more mathematical way.

Comment: You need to make some assumptions. If you can assume independence and constant daily probability, you have a simple basis to construct an answer.

Comment: @Glen_b Ok, so: the person every day can chose to wear or not the device, that means yes or no? 50%? Also, every day is independent from the another, there are no extra conditions.

Comment: @Nahuel If the probability of wearing it on any one day is $50/50$, what is the probability of wearing it $21$ straight days? How do you calculate that?

Comment: @Dave the probability of wear it today is 50%, the probability of wear it tomorrow is also 50%, and so on. Mmm… the probability of using it today AND tomorrow means multiplication? P(today) x P(tomorrow)? 0.50 x 0.50?

Comment: Good! So what is the probability of wearing it all $21$ days?

Comment: The result should be very low.. 0.5^21 I am right? IF that is so... that 0.802 is not probability...

Comment: So if the one-day probability to the $21$ equals the $21$-day probability, what one-day probability do you need for the $21$-day probability to equal $0.802?$

Comment: Are you telling me something like this?:  `p(x)^21=0.802`

Comment: Yes! Now you can calculate your one-day probability. (And then do you see how to calculate the $31$-day probability?)

Comment: yes! thank you @Dave for your help. Thank you Arya and Glen. I will go back to my books immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has got to the result with a little guidance from Dave, but for completeness, here's the result.

If we assume independence we can apply the multiplication rule ($P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$), and if we assume constant probability $p$ across days, we have $P(\text{wear all 31 days}) = p^{31}$ where $p^{21}=0.802$, or  $0.802^{(31/21)}$.

However, this is for a specific 31 days. If you were looking at a person for several months, the chance that there was *some* period of 31 days would be much higher.

Comment: Thank you @Glen_b for the clean explanation. You had been so helpful. Thank you.